# Normal map causes weird looking texture

Tags: normal-map

Why do the texture looks like on the screenshot when i use normal map? What is causing this?
Can You, please help me and explain how to fix it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: A look at the normal map could help

Comment: 4 is a very high strength for a Normal Map. Generally it looks best to stay below 1, and many maps look best around the 0.5 area.

Comment: I intentionally set it so high in order to show that weird effect. Even if i set strength to 0 and bake the normal map it will be still visible in the game.

Comment: Even with no map? Hmmm. It's hard to tell then without seeing the normal map as  Frederik Steinmetz suggested in his comment, or better yet, the project itself (or a minimal example). If you want to post it so we can have a look, you can do it here - https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Here's the project: [link](https://blend-exchange.com/b/Z5dKwKXm/)